# Small white spots on rose leaves

Tags: leaves, roses

My rose leaves have small white spots on a few of the leaves. Since there were more today than the last time I looked, I want to nip this problem in the bud if possible. Any idea what this is? I couldn't see any insects anywhere.

[image: rose leaves with spots]

Comment: @Daanil This looks like regrowth from where bugs were eating your rose plant leaves. It would seem the roses have recovered nicely.

Comment: Rob, there are more small white spots every day, and they are spreading to more leaves. But it doesn't look like anything is eating the leaves, as there are no holes but just places where the green is gone. I saw some aphids and sprayed the area with detergent water. I guess I'll keep monitoring and see what happens.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that this is scale, try some Malathion.

Comment: Rob, I looked for signs of scale or other insects and couldn't find any. But the damage is spreading rapidly so for safety's sake I'll get some Malathion tomorrow and try it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same thing and it ultimately developed to a point where all the leaves were eaten away.  This may be a problem with rose slugs (sawfly larvae).  One thing I've been trying is heavy doses of Neem Oil spray all over the leaves.  To the point where they are dripping from the oil.